# External User not part of company directory

Tags: user, directory

I am trying to share a document folder to an external user that has his own Microsoft 365 account. We are apart of two different companies, both with their own SharePoint sites. When I send him an invitation to view the document library, he receives the email. The problem is that when he clicks on the link, he receives the following error:

> "this user is not apart of the company directory"

Any thoughts on how to fix this??